# How to add multiple email addresses in the Endpoint Field under AWS SNS Subscription?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sns

I'm working on AWS SNS Topics. I need to add more than one email address in the endpoint field as seen in the image below.

I want to add for ex. - helloworld@gmail.com, helloworld@yahoo.com and so on. How do I specify multiple email addresses in the endpoint field?

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Did you find out how?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate endpoint for each email you wish to deliver messages to